# cloudflare and WCF

Tags: wcf, cloudflare, nettcpbinding

Does cloudflare support WCF specifically the `netTcpBinding` binding and if so how?

According to the [cloudflare docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/network-ports/):

> By default, Cloudflare proxies traffic destined for the HTTP/HTTPS ports listed below.

When I route my WCF service via Cloudflare (port 2096) i encounter the following error:

> You have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support .Net Framing. It is possible that you are encountering an HTTP endpoint.

The WCF service otherwise works when going direct (not thru cloudflare)

I assume there is something proprietary in `netTcpBinding` which cloudflare doesnt honour and it breaks it - as an aside the `basicHttpBinding` binding works via CF